# Teleport pad sometimes keeps teleporting me back onto the ship instead of down to the planet

Tags: starbound

My teleport pad will sometimes keep teleporting me back onto the ship instead of down to the planet. Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: We don't do well with questions like this.  Try to ask for a solution to the problem you're facing (presumably that you can't teleport down to a planet) rather than asking when a dev will implement a bug fix.

Comment: I've noticed when I try to engage the teleporter it gives me two (technically three) options to either teleport home or down to the planet (or cancel, the third).  Don't have the exact wording on me here at work, but are you clicking the Home one?  Does using the button on the right margin to teleport down bring you back to the ship ever?

Answer (score 2):

The answer, unfortunately, is that there might not be anything you can do. Starbound is in early beta, so right now, it is going to have lots of bugs and is rather likely to crash.

What you can do is [go to Starbound's forums to submit a bug report](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/general-bug-reports.34306/). Hopefully, the devs will address whatever is causing your problem soon.

Comment: I know from your edit history that you know this is a bug and to file it with the Starbound devs. Unfortunately, there isn't any way to know when (or if) they'll address your issue. I would guess, though, that either lots of people will have this issue, making it a high-priority bug, or that some wires got crossed in your save files, meaning the bug might go away the next time they wipe characters and maps.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this always happens if the target location has been removed (flag or teleporter was physically destroyed), but is still in bookmarks.

If that is the case, you'll have to walk to the location you want to visit.